# Multiple SELECT statements for multiple independent outputs

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a database in SQL Server listing maritime incidents containing the date of each.
For a chart illustration I now want to write a SQL statement (for Visual Studio) which gives the total number of incidents for each year.

Example:

**2009 2010    (Year - X Axes)**

**4575  5432   (Years - Y Axes)**

The SELECT statement for the X axes, I can write like

```
SELECT year1, year2 FROM (SELECT 2009 AS year1) AS a, ( SELECT 2010 AS year2) AS b
```

But what about the second one?
When I write something like:

```
SELECT totalyear1, totalyear2 FROM (SELECT COUNT(Reference) FROM STO.dbo.STOMaritimeIncidents WHERE [Incident date] = 2010 AS totalyear1) AS a, (SELECT COUNT(Reference) FROM STO.dbo.STOMaritimeIncidents WHERE [Incident date] = 2009 AS totalyear2) AS b
```

I get Errors like "*Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'*."

I would really appreciate if someone can give me an explanation or help me with it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AS totalyear1` and `AS totalyear2` alias declarations need to be made on the columns themselves:

```
SELECT totalyear1, totalyear2 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(Reference) AS totalyear1 
      FROM STO.dbo.STOMaritimeIncidents 
      WHERE [Incident date] = 2010) AS a, 
     (SELECT COUNT(Reference) AS totalyear2 
      FROM STO.dbo.STOMaritimeIncidents 
      WHERE [Incident date] = 2009) AS b
```

You can improve this by simply doing this in one query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Incident date] = 2010 THEN 1 ELSE 0) as totalyear1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Incident date] = 2009 THEN 1 ELSE 0) as totalyear2
FROM STO.dbo.STOMaritimeIncidents
```

And if you don't mind (or prefer) pivoting the data, you can use @Umair's suggestion and use COUNT with a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

P.s you can do everything in one query! Such as

```
SELECT [Incident date], Total = COUNT(Reference) 
FROM STO.dbo.STOMaritimeIncidents
GROUP BY [Incident date]
WHERE [Incident date] IN (2009, 2010)
```

As for your actual error, it is because of the line `...WHERE [Incident date] = 2009 AS totalyear2` etc. It needs to be in the following format (alias' need to be on the columns)

```
SELECT totalyear2 = COUNT(Reference) FROM STO.dbo.STOMaritimeIncidents WHERE [Incident date] = 2010
```

Comment: This works nicely, except the data is pivoted - not the same result as original query.  Also `Total = COUNT(Reference)` should probably be `COUNT(Reference) AS Total`

Comment: Ah yes. Good catch. I will mention that.

Comment: @PinnyM `Total = COUNT(Reference)` and `COUNT(Reference) AS Total` are the same thing are they not? However it is more clear with `AS`!

Comment: I don't recall seeing that syntax for SQL Server - do you have a source for this?  It's generally used for assigning variables...

Comment: Indeed i do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981938/what-is-your-preferred-syntax-for-sql-aliases

Comment: Yup it is indeed valid (clarity can be debated either way)- but only for SQL Server 2012.  The OP has 2010 tagged.

Comment: Actually no it is available for earlier versions. I am currently using sql server 2005 and it is fine.

Comment: Thanks, guess I learned something new :)  The post you linked to is from '09 so you must be correct.  Oddly enough, I can't find any MS source that mentions it.